# Can I change radiobutton control's visibility

Tags: c#, winforms

In given below Image I am showing radio button ,Can i remove arrow shown circle of radio button ,is it possible ? I need to show on radio button's `image` and `text` ,not its sign , I know i can use any other control like button or label, but Actually I have done all coding using radio button ,and now design of form got changed ,and now i don't want to change whole my code again , so is their any trick to solve this issue ?

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you removed the bit `Solve this issue?`. What exactly do you mean **Can i remove arrow shown circle of radio button**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Appearance` property like this:

```
radioButton1.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
```

Comment: Thank s alot , you saved my lot of time :)